# Dual boot Ubuntu on macOS Big Sur Macbook Pro 16" 2019

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, mac, multi-boot

I would like to install Ubuntu Desktop, 18.04 or 20.04 on my MacBook Pro 2019 16" so it would be on dual boot, but I'm having problems with it. My MBP is running Big Sur 11.5.2. Right now, I have Windows 10 installed with Bootcamp.

Problem description:

- Start MBP holding Option button.

  [image: screenshot]
- Select either of the flash drive ones and after about 5 seconds, I get Apple logo on the screen with loading bar.
- Then it shows that there's a necessary update.

  [image: screenshot]
- I click the Update button, and the Apple logo comes on with a loading progress bar.
- shutdown
- boots up
- Apple logo with a progress bar
- Hold down the Option key to get the Boot Select menu.
- Select USB drive.

All of the above repeats itself.

What have I done:

- I tried different Linux distros.
- I tried Sandisk USB-C flash drive and also type-a flash drive with Apple USB-C to USB-A adapter. It made no difference. Both show up the same on the Startup Manager window.
- I tried the same flash drives on my older MBP where there is no T2 chip. It works like a charm.
- entered recovery mode, Startup Security Utility, under *Secure Boot*, selected *No Security*. Under *External Boot*, selected *Allow booting from external drive*.
- I used balenaEtcher for writing ISO to a USB flash drive.
- For x reason, I also made separate partition for Ubuntu, but that didn't change a thing. I just thought that maybe macOS wants to see a separate partition or something like that.
- I tried my coworker's MacBook Pro, exactly the same model, specs, etc. and had exactly the same problem.

Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to install Linux as dual boot on a MBP with a T2 chip?

Answer (score 2):

> Linux support for the Keyboard & Trackpad, the networking drivers, and
> the T2 security chip only just recently got merged into the mainline
> Linux Kernel.   I'm fairly sure you need at least kernel version 5.4+
> to get some of these features working and I believe v5.6 may be
> necessary for T2 support.   I don't recall which of the post v5.4
> releases has T2 support.
>
> **Currently you cannot easily install Linux onto an Apple computer which uses the T2 security chip because the Linux Kernel with the T2
> support is not included in any of the currently released distributions
> as a default kernel.**   If you want to run Linux on this laptop, then
> you will most likely need to first install Linux to an older Mac or
> other UEFI booting PC and install the latest v5.6 kernel.   I would
> suggest trying to boot this customized Linux boot disk externally to
> confirm you use the built-in keyboard, trackpad, and either WiFi or
> ethernet.  Then clone the Linux install to the internal SSD (again you
> will need a boot disk with support for the T2 security chip).
>
> I do not recommend dual booting this laptop with both macOS and Linux
> unless you have good backups and are prepared to perform a clean
> install or restore from backup since you will at some point most
> likely do something which will prevent either OS from booting and
> possibly risk losing access to all the data in one or both operating
> systems.
>
> You cannot disable the T2 chip as it is an integral part of the
> system.   The most you can do is disable some of the security settings
> to allow a non-Apple OS to boot and to allow booting from an external
> drive.

[discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251260029)

Answer (score 1):

I had followed the guide on https://wiki.t2linux.org/ and was successful. You may even contact their discord server for help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Get a small mini computer or laptop refurbished. Or thrift stores.
They won't cost much should be under $100 some around 50. Small.

Switch between two monitor sources, HDMI, etc, ON the monitor control. No, you can't see both at the same time, but you could use a network for that, if you want to..., in real time. Even old computers. VNC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer doesn't solve the problem: how do I install Linux on my MacBook Pro? It's more of a "here's another idea"